# Evaluate $\int^{441}_0\frac{\pi\sin \pi \sqrt x}{\sqrt x} dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

Evaluate this definite integral:
$$\int^{441}_0\frac{\pi\sin \pi \sqrt x}{\sqrt x} dx$$

Comment: One *evaluates* or *calculates* integrals, rather than *solving* them. One *solves* equations, problems, &c.

Comment: Right! I'm sorry for the mistake, will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This integral (even the indefinite one) can be easily solved by observing:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\pi\sqrt x = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt x}$$

which implies that:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos\pi\sqrt x = -\frac{\pi \sin\pi\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}$$

Finally, we obtain:

$$\int\frac{\pi\sin\pi\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx = -2\cos\pi\sqrt x$$

whence the definite integral with bounds $0, n^2$ evaluates to $2(1-(-1)^n)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int^{441}_0\frac{\pi\sin \pi \sqrt x}{\sqrt x} dx$$
$$\implies\pi\int^{441}_0\frac{\sin \pi \sqrt x}{\sqrt x} dx$$
$$\implies\pi\int^{21}_0\frac{2u \sin \pi u}{u} du$$
$$\implies2\pi\int^{21}_0 \sin{\pi u}\;du$$
$$\implies2\pi\int^{21\pi}_0 \frac{\sin{v}}{\pi}\;dv$$
$$\implies2\int^{21\pi}_0 \sin{v}\;dv$$
$$\implies -2 \left[\cos \pi \sqrt x\right]^{21}_{0}$$
$$\implies-2(\cos 21\pi - \cos 0)$$
$$\implies-2(-1 - 1)$$
$$\implies-2\times (-2)$$
$$\implies 4$$

An interesting thing is that for upper bounds that are squares of *even* numbers this evaluates to zero, while for squares of *odd* numbers (such as $21^2 = 441$) this evaluates to 4.

Comment: I guess I would have made a single substitution of $ u = \pi \sqrt{x} $ so as to limit the number of times substitution has to be used, but yes that looks good regardless. As for the mention of the evenness and oddness of the resulting number just replace the upper bound with the number $n^2$ and you get as the resulting answer (when evaluated from zero to n as per the substitution) $$ -2 (\cos(n \pi) - 1 ) = -2 ( (-1)^n - 1)$$ which is non zero when n is odd and zero when n is even.

Comment: That's a useful observation, missed that.